# Question in combinatorics on dominoes

Tags: combinatorics

> An  $8 \times 8$ grid is covered with 32 dominoes (each square on a
> domino equals one square in the grid). Show that the number of
> dominoes lying horizontally is an even number.

*Hint: Color all the squares in every other column black. How many black squares cover a vertical domino? Are the number of black squares covered by vertical tiles together an even or an odd number? How many black squares cover a horizontal tile? Can the number of horizontal tiles be an odd number?*

My answer is:

Let the number of squares in the $x$ direction be $8$, and let the number of squares in the $y$ direction be $8$. Let every other column be colored black, thus $4$ columns are colored black. For each black column, we can arrange $\frac{8}{2}=4$ vertical dominoes, which is an even number. For this specific case, we then obtain the total number of black squares covered by vertical tiles to be $8\times4=32$, which is also an even number. For the horizontal dominoes, we have the following: Every horizontal domino covers one black square. Since we have the total number of black squares being 32, the remaining maximum number of horizontal dominoes is $\frac{32}{2}=16$, which is an even number. But since one can not place any horizontal dominoes on the board if all the black squares are covered by vertical ones, then the maximum number of dominoes lying horizontally is $16$, which is an even number.

But unfortunately, this is not correct. Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Your conclusion is 'the maximum number is 16' , and the question was not about maximum or minimum number of horizontal dominos.  Your conclusion is : 'the maximum is 16', so eventually, the number of horizontal dominos is 5, which is odd. And the objective is to demonstrate that 5 (or any odd integer) is impossible. BTW, you explain that we have maximum 16 horizontal dominoes, which is false.

Comment: let $v$ be the number of vertical dominos. And $v_b$ the number of vertical dominos in black columns.  How many black squares are covered with a vertical domino ? How many remaining black squares ? Then you can conclude.

Comment: Each vertical domino cover an even number of black tiles while each horizontal domino covers a single black tile. If you have an odd number of horizontal dominos, can you cover an even number of black tiles?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja the problem is that I have no idea how to play domino, so I fear that the lack of knowing the rules of the game are disturbing my clarity here.

Comment: Your argument is unnecessarily complicated ... you can prove the statement much more easily! Consider what @RezhaAdrianTanuharja says above

Comment: "the problem is that I have no idea how to play domino" =>   Ah!  OK, in this problem you don;t need to follow actual domino placement rules ... just think about this problem physically: you are placing 2 x 1 objects into a 8 x 8 grid

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Let the number of squares in the \textit{x} direction be 8, and let the number of squares in the \textit{y} direction be 8. Let every other column be colored black, thus 4 columns are colored black. Since one black square is covered by a vertical domino, then the max number of dominos in a column is  4. Furthermore, each vertical domino covers an even number of black tiles while each horizontal domino covers a single black tile. Therefore, if we have an odd number of horizontal dominos, then we cannot cover an even number of black tiles.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz yes and everything before the word furthermore in your comment is unnecessary and irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colour the entire 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th rows of the board black and the others white.  Clearly, every domino lying horizontally covers $2$ squares of the same colour and every domino lying vertically covers $1$ black square and $1$ white square. Now, suppose there are $x$ dominoes lying horizontally along the black rows and $y$ dominoes lying horizontally along the white rows. Then, the number of black squares is

$$
2x+0y+1(32-x-y)=32 \\
x+32-y=32 \\
x=y
$$

Hence, the total number of dominoes lying horizontal is $x+y=2x$ is even.